# Searching and highlighting text works fine in HTML , but doesn't work in PDF (using UIWebView)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

I am  able to search and highlight text in `HTML` File (using `UIWebView`), But in PDF it is not working(using `UIWebView`). Please help. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11909341/pdf-highlighting-above-image-below-text

Comment: PDFs are different kind of files and data, requires different ways to read them. You need to look into libs like https://github.com/iwelabs/ILPDFKit and https://github.com/KurtCode/PDFKitten.

Comment: Okay @ Omraj, iphonic, let me check this.

Comment: I tried but still not working , May anyone help me, how to search and highlight text in HTML File (using UIWebView),

Answer (score 0):

Old answers which will help u for sure :

[PDF search on the iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4097044/pdf-search-on-the-iphone)

[PDF Manipulation on iPhone SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5234408/pdf-manipulation-on-iphone-sdk)

[search feature in a PDF in iphone sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686924/which-are-the-pdf-operators-needed-to-do-a-search-feature-in-a-pdf-in-iphone-sdk)

Comment: I tried, but still this is not working on pdf file, only works on HTML file, any other suggestion would be great . Thank in advance .